# Add Properties to a base class so they show on Visual Studio's Properties window?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, properties, base-class

I have this class:

```
public class CameraWindow : PictureBox
```

How can i add a property that will show up here:

[image]

It's prolly really easy but i cant find a way of doing that =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate the property with the [Browsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) attribute.

e.g.

```
public class CameraWindow : PictureBox
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public int MyProperty{get;set;}
}
```

You can also add a [Category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) attribute if you want your property to appear in a specific grouping in the properties window.

Comment: `'System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

Comment: @Danpe: see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

using System.ComponentModel;

```
[Browsable(true)]
public bool SampleProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it shows up on `Misc` catagory.
Can i change the catagory ?

Comment: @Danpe: yes - see the last part of my answer.

Comment: yes simple use     [Category("My Properties")]

    public string MyCustomProperty{ get; set; }